# Can't find mistake -- 'segmentation fault' - in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote this function but can't get on the problem that gives me 'segmentation fault' msg.

Thank you for any help guys !!

```
/*This function extract all header files in a *.c1 file*/

void includes_extractor(FILE *c1_fp, char *c1_file_name ,int c1_file_str_len )
{
    int i=0;
    FILE *c2_fp , *header_fp;
    char ch, *c2_file_name,header_name[80]; /* we can assume line length 80 chars MAX*/
    char inc_name[]="include"; 
    char inc_chk[INCLUDE_LEN+1]; /*INCLUDE_LEN is defined | +1 for null*/

    /* making the c2 file name */

    c2_file_name=(char *) malloc ((c1_file_str_len)*sizeof(char));
    if (c2_file_name == NULL)
    {
     printf("Out of memory !\n");
     exit(0);
    } 

    strcpy(c2_file_name , c1_file_name); 
    c2_file_name[c1_file_str_len-1] = '\0'; 
    c2_file_name[c1_file_str_len-2] = '2';

/*Open source & destination files + ERR check */

    if( !(c1_fp = fopen (c1_file_name,"r") ) )
    {
     fprintf(stderr,"\ncannot open *.c1 file !\n");
     exit(0);
    }

    if( !(c2_fp = fopen (c2_file_name,"w+") ) )
    {
     fprintf(stderr,"\ncannot open *.c2 file !\n");
     exit(0);
    }

/*next code lines are copy char by char from c1 to c2,
  but if meet header file, copy its content */

    ch=fgetc(c1_fp);
    while (!feof(c1_fp))
    {
        i=0;    /*zero i */ 
        if (ch == '#') /*potential #include case*/
        {
             fgets(inc_chk, INCLUDE_LEN+1, c1_fp); /*8 places for "include" + null*/
         if(strcmp(inc_chk,inc_name)==0) /*case #include*/
         {
          ch=fgetc(c1_fp);
          while(ch==' ') /* stop when head with a '<' or '"' */
          {
           ch=fgetc(c1_fp);
          } /*while(2)*/

          ch=fgetc(c1_fp); /*start read header file name*/

          while((ch!='"') || (ch!='>')) /*until we get the end of header name*/
          {
           header_name[i] = ch;
           i++;
           ch=fgetc(c1_fp);
          }/*while(3)*/
          header_name[i]='\0';  /*close the header_name array*/


          if( !(header_fp = fopen (header_name,"r") ) ) /*open *.h for read + ERR chk*/
          {
               fprintf(stderr,"cannot open header file !\n");
           exit(0);
              }
          while (!feof(header_fp)) /*copy header file content to *.c2 file*/
          {
           ch=fgetc(header_fp);
           fputc(ch,c2_fp);
          }/*while(4)*/
          fclose(header_fp);
         }
                }/*frst if*/
        else
        {
         fputc(ch,c2_fp);
        }
     ch=fgetc(c1_fp); 
    }/*while(1)*/ 

fclose(c1_fp);
fclose(c2_fp);
free (c2_file_name);    
}
```

Comment: Did you run it through a debugger?  What line did it crash on?

Comment: Consider compiling with debug options (eg -g3) and run a debugger (eg gdb). It will find the offending line. If not, use tools like valgrind or electric fence which focus on this particular concern.

Comment: `i=0;    /*zero i */ ` This is probably one of the most unhelpful comments I've ever seen.

Comment: As a suggestion, don't use `strcpy` unless you have verified the size of the input before using it. Or just never use `strcpy` at all.

Comment: @Rosh: He actually can safely use `strcpy`, because he allocates memory based on source string length. (Plus one, hopefully!)

Comment: @Al Kepp: It's the "hopefully" part where `strcpy` becomes unsafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code seems to contain many errors, but the most evident to me is

```
while((ch!='"') || (ch!='>')) /*until we get the end of header name*/
```

I would say that every character is either different from `'"'` **or** from `'>'` ... or do you know a character that can be equal to both? ;-)

Comment: Exactly! There is `or` instead of `and`, and also many other weird code constructions.

Comment: what is the mistake ? 
It means: until we get ' " ' or ' > ' we keep the while loop.
Once we head with ' " ' OR '  > ' stop loop.

Comment: It does mean WHILE, not UNTIL! So you have got an endless loop.

Comment: It's not endless - it quickly corrupts the stack frame :)

Comment: Another question... I see this 'ÿ' char after every include file that been extracted. How can I delete this char by changing something in my code ? 10x !

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a shot in the dark here and guess that the `c1_file_str_len` argument is the result from a `strlen()` function call, which does not take into account the terminating NULL character. Your call to `strcpy` could (would?) then fail.

If not, maybe you could provide some more help here? Tried debugging? At which line does this segfault occur?

Comment: Nothing helped? Really? Interesting. I simply put it to Visual Studio, compiled and run and it crashed on your `while` statement. It took just 2 seconds to see that there should be `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: I think we have a solution here, Mosh. You should probably teach yourself how to use a debugger, I'm sure it'll come in handy for you later.

Comment: @Al Kepp: Agreed - I ran it under Mac OS X and it generated a Bus error which gdb found immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Run your program under [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org).

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
while((ch!='"') || (ch!='>'))
```

to:

```
while((ch!='"') && (ch!='>'))
```

You are over-running the header_name buffer as you are failing to stop at the end of the include name.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is here:

```
while((ch!='"') || (ch!='>')) /*until we get the end of header name*/
```

There should be `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or), because this is an endless loop. ("Repeat while character isn't " or isn't >." At least one of those two conditions is always true, so it loops until a segmentation fault occurs.)

Also, there are many other flaws in your source code. But this one definitely generates segmantetion fault.

Additional notes:

- There should be just a single parameter in your function: the source file name
- `FILE *c1_fp` should be just a local variable.
- `int c1_file_str_len` should be computed using strlen(), and you must add 1, otherwise your allocation for second file name misses `'\0'`.
- You should prefer `return;` over `exit(0);` and also close files and free allocated memory before exit.

Also, you should make the function recursive to let it searches for #include directives in the #included files as well. And you should support "include directories" setting - list of directories where to search .h files for.

Comment: Another question...
I see this 'ÿ' char after every include file that been extracted.
How can I delete this char by changing something in my code ?

10x !

Comment: Mosh, tell us byte value of that 'ÿ'. (Watch it in hex viewer.) It can be just something you really have at the end or even at the beginning of each file.